# Why does my unit test fail to recognize the regex used in my search method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have a program which can perform case-insensitive query searches in a repository based on a name (a given name, a last name or both). But every time I run my unit test in JUnit 5, it seems to be unable to recognize that I'm using a regex so it always fails.

Here is how my search methods in my service class look like:

```
public List<Record1> searchRecord1ByName(String givenName, String lastName) {
        return searchRecord(givenName, lastName,
                (gn, ln) -> record1Repo.findByGivenNameAndLastName(gn, ln),
                (gn, ln) -> record1Repo.findByGivenName(gn),
                (gn, ln) -> record1Repo.findByLastName(ln));
    }

public <T> List<T> searchRecord(String givenName, String lastName,
                                        BiFunction<String, String, List<T>> searchBothNames,
                                        BiFunction<String, String, List<T>> searchGivenName,
                                        BiFunction<String, String, List<T>> searchLastName) {
        if ((givenName == null || givenName.isEmpty()) && (lastName == null || lastName.isEmpty())) {
            throw new InvalidSearchDataException("Both givenName and lastName cannot be null or empty.");
        }

        String givenNameRegex = givenName != null && !given.isEmpty() ? "^" + Pattern.quote(givenName) + "$" : null;
        String lastNameRegex = lastName != null && !lastName.isEmpty() ? "^" + Pattern.quote(lastName) + "$" : null;

        if (givenNameRegex != null && lastNameRegex != null) {
            return searchBothNames.apply(givenNameRegex, lastNameRegex);
        } else if (givenNameRegex != null) {
            return searchGivenName.apply(givenNameRegex, null);
        } else {
            return searchLastName.apply(null, lastNameRegex);
        }
    }
```

Here is my repository method to search by given name (I'm using MongoDB):

```
@Query("{ 'givenName': { $regex: ?0, $options: 'i' } }")
List<Record1> findByGivenName(String givenName);
```

And here is my unit test (it's just for givenName, but the other 2 cases would be identical):

```
private final RecordSearchService recordSearchService = new RecordSearchService(mockRecord1Repo, mockRecord2Repo, mockRecord3Repo);

@Test
    void searchRecord1ByGivenName() {
        Record1 record1 = Record1.builder()
                .givenName("TestGivenName")
                .lastName("TestLastName")
                .build();

        List<Record1> expected = List.of(record1);
        when(mockRecord1Repo.findByGivenName(anyString())).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
            String givenNameArg = invocation.getArgument(0);
            return givenNameArg.equalsIgnoreCase("testgivenname") ? expected : Collections.emptyList();
        });

        List<Record1> upperActual = recordSearchService.searchRecord1ByName("TESTGIVENNAME", null);
        List<Record1> lowerActual = recordSearchService.searchRecord1ByName("testgivenname", null);
        List<Record1> mixedActual = recordSearchService.searchRecord1ByName("TestGivenName", null);

        verify(mockRecord1Repo).findByGivenName("TESTGIVENNAME");
        verify(mockRecord1Repo).findByGivenName("testgivenname");
        verify(mockRecord1Repo).findByGivenName("TestGivenName");
        assertEquals(expected, upperActual);
        assertEquals(expected, lowerActual);
        assertEquals(expected, mixedActual);
    }
```

It should actually pass when using this input but that's what I get:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
record1Repo.findByGivenName(
    "TESTGIVENNAME"
);

Actual invocations have different arguments:
record1Repo.findByGivenName(
    "^\TESTGIVENNAME\E$"
);

record1Repo.findByGivenName(
    "^\testgivenname\E$"
);

record1Repo.findByGivenName(
    "^\TestGivenName\E$"
);
```

Why isn't my unit test working and how do I fix it? The program is otherwise working normally for me, it's just the unit test that is causing me problems. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you call `record1Repo` you are passing the regexes you've constructed. Step through your code with the debugger.

Comment: `searchGivenName.apply(givenNameRegex, null)` this line is calling `findByGivenName` with the `givenNameRegex`, not the `givenName`.
I think you need to change your test to expect the givenNameRegex, not the givenName

Comment: Do you mean `verify(mockRecord1Repo).findByGivenName("^\\QTESTGIVENNAME\\E$");`?
When doing this and my test reaches assertEquals I get an `org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :[Record1[givenName=TestGivenName, lastName=TestLastName]]
Actual   :[]`

Comment: Your test `searchRecord1ByGivenName` Answer defines `givenNameArg` but uses `lastNameArg`. Can you double-check that your code excerpt is exactly the code you're having trouble with?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It's actually `givenNameArg`. I edited my post. Otherwise everything else including the errors I get is the same.

Comment: You are passing `Pattern` instances to your method, but verifying with strings. Patterns are not strings (and you cannot compare them with `equals`). Next, you are calling `assertEquals` on the same value with 3 different expected values (upper, lower, mixed), that cannot work (a value cannot be equal to 3 distinct values at the same time)

Comment: Using patterns in my `when()` and `verify()` methods actually solved the problem for me, thank you!